# Maximum number of consecutively selected rows.

Tags: number-theory

You have a table, where the nth column repeats itself every p_n times (mod p_n). For example with n=5, you'd get a table like this, with the first column being mod 2, with the 5th column being mod 11:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBc4g.jpg

If you can select one residue class (i.e one "number" in a column) from each column, what is the maximum number of consecutive rows that can be selected?

**Examples**

For example for n=4 (i.e with mod 2,3,5,7 in the 4 columns) the maximum number of consecutively covered / selected rows is 9.

[image: http://imgur.com/QRM4oth]

For n=5 (i.e with mod 2,3,5,7,11) the maximum number of consecutively covered / selected rows that you can construct is 13

[image: http://imgur.com/VkKLcQO]

My question is, is there some sort of method / algorithm which would allow you to calculate the maximum number of consecutively selected rows, for a certain n?

**Edit**:

The maximum number of consecutively selected rows corresponds to this sequence

http://oeis.org/A058989

However my question remains the same: is there some sort of method / algorithm which would allow you to calculate the maximum number of consecutively selected rows, for a certain n?

Comment: You can insert images directly into posts by clicking the button that looks like an image.